# Why is any code executed before this has finished?

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

Supposing I have a code like this:

```
[ApiConnection getServerTimeWithBlock:^(BOOL gotTimeResponse){

    if(gotTimeResponse)
    {
        //we're online, got the response from time endpoint
        [ApiConnection registerNewCustomerWithBlock:^(NSString* val){
            if(val)
            {
                NSLog(@"val: %@",val);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"no val");
            }
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        //we're offline
    }
}];

NSLog(@"TEST");
```

why is the last NSLog executed before the whole first block has finished execution?

Comment: Looks like it would benefit you to read up about blocks & async coding in general - this sort of structure is so useful

Comment: @SomaMan definitely yes, that's what I'm doing atm. My fault here seems to be that I thought the method will return only after the completion handler has executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably `getServerTimeWithBlock:` is exectuted *asynchronously*. When supplying the block, you're telling the APIConnection object what to do when it has finished getting the server time. This will involve network fetches and reading data back, which you don't want to wait for on the main thread as this will cause your UI to freeze. Your program therefore carries on, and the block is executed whenever the fetch is complete.

Note that blocks do not imply that asynchronous or multithreaded code is in use (see NSArray's enumerateWithBlock: method, for example) but it seems very likely to be the case here.

Comment: I think I need to check the internet connection synchronously, because otherwise I don't know if I should fetch the data from the API or use the offline storage. So I think I'll use dispatch_sync for the first request and then peform all the others asynchronously, do you think this is a good approach?

Comment: No. I think you should have whatever calls the code above expect the method to return immediately, and pass in a completion block to that method. then, when you've got the data, by whatever method, you execute the completion block.

Comment: so should I keep the code as it is, and after the getServerTimeWithBlock call prepare the UI for the data, and then using completion handler in the method fill the UI with data, be it from the API or from the offline database?

Answer (score 4):

Because the `getServerTimeWithBlock:` method is asynchronous, so it returns immediately and runs on a background thread. When that thread is complete is calls the completion block.

So, the method runs before your log, but the completion block (usually) doesn't (it might if there was an error or something like that).